# Phalcon PHP: is there a way to do automatic resource routing sans annotations?

Tags: php, routes, phalcon

I'd like to do resource routing with Phalcon PHP - but I'd like to do it without having to specify all these annotations.  Is there a way to set it up, so that it's a bit more automatic?  You know, something like defining default actions for particular route types?

such as:

GET /resources => listAction

POST /resource => createAction

etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you can configure your routing, [documentation covers them extensively](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/routing.html). You can setup generic routing like below, this is normally done in the config. This is also the default route, that should work without the need to configure (apart from methods maybe).

```
// Create the router
$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router();

//Define a route
$router->add(
    "/:controller/:action/:params",
    array(
        "controller" => 1,
        "action"     => 2,
        "params"     => 3,
    )
)->via(array("POST", "GET"));
```

You can also extend the default router overriding the `handle` method and specify all of the logic there. In both cases the configured router must be injected into DI.

Comment: I actually ended up being even more specific such as addGet('/:controller', ...) going to the 'list' action, the addDelete('/:controller/{id}', ...) going to the 'delete' action etc

Comment: Yep. That would work just fine. The problem (well not really a problem) with most routers is that you have to specify every path individually, which is not really cool if you have a lot of same logic in different places. Things can get worse when you have multi-level controllers or modules. Anyway, there are plenty of ways to solve this, hope yours works for you as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign which controller/action should be called by http-method-types, like the docs describe.

```
// This route only will be matched if the HTTP method is GET
$router->addGet("/products/edit/{id}", "Products::edit");

// This route only will be matched if the HTTP method is POST
$router->addPost("/products/save", "Products::save");

// This route will be matched if the HTTP method is POST or PUT
$router->add("/products/update")->via(array("POST", "PUT"));
```

Besides that, there is a way to handle unrecognized controllers and actions within the dispatcher service via Phalcon\Events\Manager as below.

```
// config/services.php
use Phalcon\Events\Manager as EventsManager;

//...

/**
 * Dispatcher use a default namespace
 */
$di->set("dispatcher", function () {
    // catch dispatcher exceptions for HANDLER_NOT_FOUND and ACTION_NOT_FOUND
    // @see http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/api/Phalcon_Mvc_Dispatcher.html
    // @see http://forum.phalconphp.com/discussion/525/404-and-notfoundaction#C2179
    $evManager = new EventsManager();
    $evManager->attach("dispatch:beforeException", function ($event, $dispatcher, $exception) {
        switch ($exception->getCode()) {
            case Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_HANDLER_NOT_FOUND:
            case Dispatcher::EXCEPTION_ACTION_NOT_FOUND:
                $dispatcher->forward(array(
                    'controller' => 'index',
                    'action' => 'show404',
                ));
                return false;
        }
    });

    $dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
    $dispatcher->setDefaultNamespace("YourCustomNamespace\\Controllers");
    $dispatcher->setEventsManager($evManager);

    return $dispatcher;
});
```

This means you can use the default behaviour of Phalcon\Mvc\Router, define custom routes and be prepared for routes which cannot be handled by the default behaviour which aren't handled by Phalcon\Mvc\Router::notFound().

Edit/ additional info: you can use i.e. `php $this->request->isPut()//isDelete and so on...` inside of your controller to find out which request type was send.

Comment: It's always good to see some of this more in depth stuff!  Thanks!